# Как я могу импортировать куки в определённый профиль dolphin{anty} через python и их локальный api

Tags: python, request

Есть файл с куками в json формате, как я могу их импортировать в определённый профиль в dolphin{anty}, не нашёл какого-то локального метода для того что бы импортировать их, так же использовал: selenium_dolphin, но там то же слабенькая документация, поэтому не знаю есть ли там возможность или же нет.